# How to create a page with just one post?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, sqlite, flask

I am creating a small blog using Flask. But I didn't find any tutorials or information that would solve the following problem: Create a dynamic page with just one post. I want this page to appear only a complete post, that is, coming out of a database. Without showing all at once (using the for repeater)

I already have an automatic redirector that takes you to a dynamic page for each post title, I just need to know how to show just one post on that page instead of several.

```py
@app.route('/<url_post>', methods=['GET'])
def daily_post(url_post):
    with sqlite3.connect("sample.db") as connection:

        c = connection.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM posts")
        data = c.fetchall()
```

Page Post.html

```html
    {% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}

    {% for item in data %}
        <article class="media content-section">
          <div class="media-body">

            <div class="article-metadata">


              <a class="mr-2" href="/home">{{ item[0] }}</a>
              <small class="text-muted">{{ item[1] }}</small>

            </div>

            <p class="article-content">{{ item[2] }}</p>
          </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

I want a dynamic page with only one post (use sqlite3)

Comment: What is the value of `url_post`? Is it stored in the `posts` db table? Typically you would want the URL to identify a single post to query out of the db and then render to the client. Something like `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.url_post=url_post`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're **grabbing every post** from within your `posts` table and are then passing that result query set into your view to be rendered. This is the problematic code:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM posts")
data = c.fetchall()
```

Instead you should be **filtering** your results with a `WHERE` clause to only extract those records that fulfill a specified condition, i.e. your specific post.

Something along the lines of:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE <table_column_identifier>=?", (url_post))
data = c.fetchall()
```

Where `<table_column_identifier>` is the column within your `posts` table schema uniquely identifying your desired post. I would have to see your table schema definition to give you the exact field, but it's probably something along the lines of `id`

**Note**: You can reuse your page post view providing your new route endpoint provides the filtering as described above.

Hopefully that helps!